# How to handle error java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, xls

I tried to read an excel file in a JSP page. But when i run the program, i get an error messsage. Could you tell me the way to handle this error or another way to read an excel file in a JSP page.

index.jsp

```
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<html>
<%
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
          new File("C://excel//excel.xlsx"));
          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
          XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
          FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator=workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
          for(Row row : sheet)
          {
              for(Cell cell : row)
              {
                  switch (formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType()) 
                  {
                     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                     System.out.println( 
                     cell.getNumericCellValue() + " \t\t " );
                     break;
                     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                     System.out.println(
                     cell.getStringCellValue() + " \t\t " );
                     break;
                  }
              }
          }

             System.out.println();
          fis.close();
          workbook.close();
    %>
    </html>
```

Error message:

> HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp
>   at line 18
>
> type Exception report
>
> message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line
>   18
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred
>   processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 18
>
> 15: <% 16:          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( 17:
>   new File("C://excel//excel.xlsx")); 18:         XSSFWorkbook workbook =
>   new XSSFWorkbook(fis); 19:          XSSFSheet sheet =
>   workbook.getSheetAt(0); 20:         FormulaEvaluator
>   formulaEvaluator=workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
>   21:         for(Row row : sheet)
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> root cause javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:170)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> root cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:132)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:132)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.26 logs.

Comment: The relevant part of your error is **NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException**. See [Installing XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/conInstallGuide.html).

Comment: i got it bro, thanks a lot.